# Angular @Input decorator and other issues

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am making the Kanban-fire app by following the tutorial on Google Codelabs. This is the link of the part where I'm facing issues. *https://developers.google.com/codelabs/building-a-web-app-with-angular-and-firebase#10*

I'm using Angular CLI 11.0.7, Node 12.18.2, Ubuntu 20.10 64bit, TypeScript 4.1.2.

As explained in the tutorial, I followed along and made all the necessary changes. Here's the issue that I'm facing.

At first, I was getting this error

*Property 'task' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.*
*19   task: Task;*

and this is my corresponding code

`@Input() task: Task;`

It uses the following Task interface

```
export interface Task {
  id?: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
}
```

I tried to solve this error by initializing the task property in @Input as

```
@Input() task: Task = {title: 'def title', description: 'def desc'};
```

and it was all good until these errors arose.

As you'll be able to see in the link that I've shared, that we have to make changes to `app.component.html` as well as some methods in `app.component.ts` file.
I made the changes and now I'm getting these errors.

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:21:34 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'CdkDragDrop<{ id: string; }[] | null, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CdkDragDrop<Task[], Task[]>'.
  Type '{ id: string; }[] | null' is not assignable to type 'Task[]'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Task[]'.

21       (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
```

and

```
Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
src/app/app.component.html:27:17 - error TS2739: Type '{ id: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Task': title, description

27         cdkDrag [task]="task"></app-task>
```

For complete reference, I am providing `app.component.html` as well as `app.component.ts` code here

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-icon>local_fire_department</mat-icon>
  <span>Kanban Fire</span>
</mat-toolbar>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <button (click)="newTask()" mat-button>
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> Add Task
  </button>
</div>

<div class="container-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Backlog</h2>
    <mat-card
      cdkDropList
      id="todo"
      #todoList="cdkDropList"
      [cdkDropListData]="todo | async"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList, inProgressList]"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
      class="list">
      <p class="empty-label" *ngIf="(todo | async)?.length === 0">Empty List</p>
      <app-task
        (edit)="editTask('todo', $event)"
        *ngFor="let task of todo | async"
        cdkDrag [task]="task"></app-task>
    </mat-card>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>In Progress</h2>
    <mat-card
      cdkDropList
      id="inProgress"
      #inProgressList="cdkDropList"
      [cdkDropListData]="inProgress | async"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList, doneList]"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
      class="list">
      <p class="empty-label" *ngIf="(inProgress | async)?.length === 0">Empty List</p>
      <app-task
        (edit)="editTask('inProgress', $event)"
        *ngFor="let task of inProgress | async"
        cdkDrag [task]="task"></app-task>
    </mat-card>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Done</h2>
    <mat-card
      cdkDropList
      id="done"
      #doneList="cdkDropList"
      [cdkDropListData]="done | async"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList, inProgressList]"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
      class="list">
      <p class="empty-label" *ngIf="(done | async)?.length === 0">Empty List</p>
      <app-task
        (edit)="editTask('done', $event)"
        *ngFor="let task of done | async"
        cdkDrag [task]=""></app-task>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from '../app/task/task';
import { CdkDragDrop, transferArrayItem } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { TaskDialogComponent } from '../app/task-dialog/task-dialog.component';
import { TaskDialogResult } from '../app/task-dialog/task-dialog.component';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  todo = this.store.collection('todo').valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
  inProgress = this.store.collection('inProgress').valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
  done = this.store.collection('done').valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private store: AngularFirestore) {}

  editTask(list: 'done' | 'todo' | 'inProgress', task: Task): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TaskDialogComponent, {
      width: '270px',
      data: {
        task,
        enableDelete: true,
      }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: TaskDialogResult) => {
      if (result.delete) {
        this.store.collection(list).doc(task.id).delete();
      } else {
        this.store.collection(list).doc(task.id).update(task);
      }
    });
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Task[]>): void {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      return;
    }
    const item = event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex];
    this.store.firestore.runTransaction(() => {
      const promise = Promise.all([
        this.store.collection(event.previousContainer.id).doc(item.id).delete(),
        this.store.collection(event.container.id).add(item),
      ]);
      return promise;
    });
    transferArrayItem(
      event.previousContainer.data,
      event.container.data,
      event.previousIndex,
      event.currentIndex
    );
  }  
  
  newTask(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TaskDialogComponent, {
      width: '270px',
      data: {
        task: {}
      }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: TaskDialogResult) => {
      this.store.collection('todo').add(result.task)
    });
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the `?` for the id on the Task Interface

Comment: Hey, can you share more code? share what the component.ts file looks like

Comment: @LakinduHewawasam that's for making the id optional, if I remove it it will make it required

Comment: @emmanuelagarry I have edited the question and shared the code you asked for

Comment: try `@Input () task: Task | null;` you can take a look to this link:https://indepth.dev/posts/1402/bulletproof-angular (I suppose you've created your app with strict-mode=true).NOTE: Yes, I know that "stric mode" can be like a great hedache. For new app, it's good the stric mode, makes more easy check, debug and updated applications (but we need take account when see "old codes")

Comment: @Eliseo thanks. It helped. I set ```strict``` and ```strictTemplates``` flag to false, and voila, it works perfect now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Eliseo for pointing this out. The strict mode being turned on caused all this to happen.

Just set `strict` and `strictTemplates` flags to false in `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in an application I was working on. I eventually paid close attention to my error message similar to yours ... your error message was --> "Property 'task' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor. 19 task: Task;

In my case my error was -->"Property 'election' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)"

my input statement was

```
@Input() election: Election
```

and I added this line in my constructor which was formerly not populated with this initialization.

```
 this.election =ELECTIONS[0]
```

this solved my problem

I guess you have to initialize in the constructor whatever it is you are trying to import.

In summary
source Component -->

```
elections-main-list.component.html

    <app-election-item
    
    *ngFor="let election of elections"
    
    [election]="election" >
    </app-election-item>
```

Import component

```
election-item-component.ts
export  class ElectionItemComponent implements OnInit{
 
  @Input() election: Election
 
  constructor() {
    this.election =ELECTIONS[0]
    
   }


As I  have only been using Angular for a short period of time the lesson I learned was to pay close attention to the error message. anyway this solution worked perfectly and on the next step....
```